# glBuffer work with one style of data but not the other, Why?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am working through some OpenGL tutorial examples and modifying them to meet my projects goals.

The problem is that the program works with this data construct (i.e. it draws a triangle)

```
    float firstTriangle[] = {
        -0.9f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  // left
        -0.0f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  // right
        -0.45f, 0.5f, 0.0f,  // top
    };

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(firstTriangle), firstTriangle, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

but it does not draw a triangle when I make the following changes:

```
    std::vector<float> thisslice;
    thisslice.push_back((float) -0.9f);
    thisslice.push_back((float) -0.5f);
    thisslice.push_back((float) 0.0f);
    thisslice.push_back((float) 0.0f);
    thisslice.push_back((float) -0.5f);
    thisslice.push_back((float) 0.0f);
    thisslice.push_back((float) -0.45f);
    thisslice.push_back((float) -0.5f);
    thisslice.push_back((float) 0.0f);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, thisslice.size() * sizeof(float), &thisslice[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: Does it matter if you use `thisslice.data()` instead of `&thisslice[0]`?

Answer (score 2):

The code presented above *should* work. It's not nice, but it should work. It makes me think you may have cut down the example for posting here? The possible reasons it might not work are:

- The vector is empty, and so thisslice[0] is an attempt to dereference
  NULL, and an exception is being thrown (which is why, as mentioned
  above, you should be using .data() instead). This *usually* only happens in debug mode though.
- The vector in your actual
  code is a const ref, which means thisslice[0] is returning a float
  (and not a float&). Taking the address is just giving you the address
  of some temp object, and not the data in the vector.

As a side note, calling push_back repeatedly is a horrible way to initialise a std::vector. Allocate the size up front, and use the [] operator for assignment of elements. Alternatively use an initialiser list, assign, or a ctor that takes begin & end.

As another side note, why are you casting a float to a float in each push_back call?

Answer (score 1):

You used `-0.5f` instead of `0.5f` as the `y` coordinate for the third vertex, so all three vertices are on a straight line and the triangle covers no area at all.